# From where does KDE get the programs to start automatically?

Tags: kde, autostart

When Evolution is installed, my KDE session automatically starts its background services like the calendar alarm notifier. I don't see startup scripts in `~/.config/autostart` and have no idea what else may be starting the services.

What are the locations that are used for starting programs/background services in a KDE desktop session?

Comment: Another location to search into would be **/etc/xdg/autostart**

Comment: @MC68020 Thank you. There is a `.service` file that may be the reason. Is there a way to deactivate it without removing the file for all users?

Comment: @allo also check `ls /run/user/1000/systemd/generator.late` maybe there are some services file generated by `systemd-xdg-autostart-generator`. But to remove it you will have to remove the `.desktop` file which may belongs to **/etc/xdg/autostart** path.